# Angularjs: Referencing an element in array of objects in templates

Tags: angularjs

I need to display three elements per row on a page, from data that I get as array, so would like ability to reference a specific element inside array.

I.e. if my array is bookList, I'd like to be able to get at 3rd element of bookList so I can pass it to a directive, for example.  Don't see an easy way to do this.

[edit]

```
{{bookList[2]}}
```

Comment: Believe maybe you're approaching the problem wrong, but hard to say without any code.  Should have the array defined on an object attached to the scope for the controller, then can have a currentPage variable there too and functions for increasing/decreasing the pages, also an array for the currently visible pages (which you can then bind to using ng-repeat on the html side).  In the controller you handle updating that secondary array based on the current page and the original array.  If they click one element and you want to pass it to something else, use ng-click="someFunc(item)"

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  Added a simple code sample of what I am trying to get at.  Quite possible it's a problem of misunderstanding how Angular is supposed to work, but it seems it would be useful to do this in some cases.

Comment: Check out string interpolation on the page here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive basically what you're doing should work as long as it's in the correct context (within an element that has the app and controller as it's ancestor and that has the scope with the bookList array)  If you provide more code or make a plunkr or jsfiddle or something online I might be able to get it working.

Answer (score 7):

Elements of the list are accessible via an integer property thus:

```
{{bookList.0}} {{bookList.1}} {{bookList.2}} ...
```

Comment: and find the last in the array with ``{{ (bookList.0*1 - 1) + bookList.length*1 }}``

Comment: Hey @EliseChant, just curious what is the logic behind the 'last in the array' shortcut... like why multiply * 1. The way I interpret is getTheValueofFirstBook then multiply 1 (which doesnt make sense to me since the string value of the book is like 'Great Expectations') then subtract one from that value then add the value of the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood,
if you have a scope variable 'bookList' which is an array containing some 'n' elements and you want to access the 2nd element directly in your template, then you can use `{{bookList[1]}}` to get it.